# Can I install Linux 4.9 kernel?

Tags: kernel

Can I install Linux 4.9 Kernel in elementary OS 0.4 that supports ***bfq*** disk I/O scheduler??? If possible, can you please point me to that repo or guide??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Ubuntu produces [mainline kernel builds](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds) packaged as .debs for easy installation. For example, here's [4.9](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.9/).

If your system is 64-bit (like most new-ish computers), you would go to the "amd64" section and download three files:

- linux-headers-4.9.0-040900_4.9.0-040900.201612111631_**all**.deb
- linux-headers-4.9.0-040900-**generic**_4.9.0-040900.201612111631_amd64.deb
- linux-image-4.9.0-040900-**generic**_4.9.0-040900.201612111631_amd64.deb

If you put them in one folder, you can install them all at once with `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.

You should be able to [boot into GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time), select "Advanced options for elementary OS", and choose the kernel version.

Note: an upstream kernel might not work out of the box, depending on your hardware! Don't be surprised if it doesn't work.

Comment: They don't have a module: `i915` and also see the question; I asked for a kernel with _**bfq**_ but these kernels use **cfq**

Comment: I get the `i915` error message too; doesn't seem to affect anything on my machine, but your mileage may vary. As for bfq, it seems it's not part of the prepackaged Ubuntu kernels, but [this slightly outdated guide](https://samvde.wordpress.com/2015/10/23/howto-compile-an-ubuntu-kernel-with-bfq-support-example-wily-2/) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install 4.9, or any other for that matter...keep in mind you could run into issues with a different kernel.

sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install ukuu
ukuu-gtk

choose your kernel > install

source:http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/upgrade-kernel-ukuu-ubuntu/

Answer (score -3):

i would say-you could install 4.9 kernel - yet Eos loki´s important drivers won´t match that kernel. I have already tested it.  But you are free to experiment. Look in around and you will find how to.